# Can't dismiss presented view when tapping empty space of the view

Tags: swift

Here is my code.

```
popoverMenuViewController = displayViewController?.popoverPresentationController

        popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue:0)
        popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = sourceViewForPopOver
        popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: sourceViewForPopOver!.bounds.midX, y: sourceViewForPopOver!.bounds.midY,width: 0,height: 0)

        self.present(displayViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I didn't set passthroughView = nil. However i still can't dismiss the presented view.

Answer (score 0):

You presented a view controller. To dismiss it, you simply call this

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: i have set modalPresentationStyle = popover. it should be able to dismiss by tapping out of the presented view right?

Comment: @henry No, you still need to handle dismiss by yourself. Property set click listener and then dismiss the view controller by that line of code